# Zend Form: Dependant field validation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a form with two select boxes: country and city, city depending on the selected country.
Note that the city field is populated dynamically when a country is selected using Ajax.

So far I extended `Zend_Form_Element_Select` overriding `isValid()` for the city select box, and I'll use the `$context` argument to get the selected country and check if the city is valid (for that country).

I want to skip city validation if the country validation fails. For example someone can inject a bad value into the country field (and the country validation will fail), and my city validation shouldn't take place and don't do that query on db, it simply shouldn't pass the validation.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `isValid()` and `setDefaults()` methods in your Form class to populate the city element when the country element is set.

```
function isValid($data) {
    if (isset($data['country'])) {
        $this->populateCity($data['country']);
    }
    return parent::isValid($data);
}

function setDefault($name, $value) {
    if ('country' === $value) {
        $this->populateCity($value);
    }
    return parent::setDefault($name, $value);
}
```

Comment: This way I don't skip the query on the database to select cities when the country is not valid. But you actually gave me a good idea! Wouldn't it be better to populate the city element only if the country element is valid? Is it OK?

Comment: I've got the solution. I'll edit this answer to post the code that actually solved my problem and accept it later :)

Comment: I still had no time to edit this answer, so I check this answer as accepted. I used only the isValid() part. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Very useful answer s3v3n! There is just a little mistake. In setDefault method I think, that you should change the if statement to if('country'=== $name) instead of if('country'=== $value).